# How to change the end_session_url in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, vaadin, wildfly, keycloak-rest-api

I have a Dockerized stack with Keycloak, Vaadin, and Wildfly. Wildfly communicates with Keycloak over kc-net. When Vaadin invokes `VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent().logout()`, Wildfly sends a `POST` request to the `end_session_url`, which is currently set to http://localhost..., resulting in a `404 error`.

How can I change the end_session_url to use "http://kc-net" instead of "http://localhost"?

I don't want to change the frontend URL, as that would require adding kc-net to `/etc/hosts` as localhost.